# How do I associate a model with multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, rails-migrations

I'm a brand new developer so this might be a dumb question.

I am trying to setup a webapp which will store stats on geographic data.

- I have a model called **Stat** which has fields for basic statistical information (median, variance, avg, etc.).
- I have setup models for each geographic units **City**, **Zip**, **Sub-Zip**

What I want to do know is associate the Stat model with Cities, Zips, and Sub-Zips; that is every stat model belongs to either a city, zip, or sub-zip while a geographic unit (city,zip,sub-zip) can have multiple stats.

How do I setup the associations and migration to do this? I've looked through the Rails guides but it doesn't seem to cover a relationship where an object can belong to different models (but only one of them). Or should I set up my models differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> every stat model belongs to either a city, zip, or sub-zip while a
>   geographic unit (city,zip,sub-zip) can have multiple stats.

So I think you want to set up [**Polymorphic Associations**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations):

> With polymorphic associations, a model can belong to more than one
>   other model, on a single association.

So your association maybe like this:

```
class Stat
  belongs_to :statsable, polymorphic: true
end

class City
  has_many :stats, as: :statsable
end

class Zip
  has_many :stats, as: :statsable
end

class Subzip
  has_many :stats, as: :statsable
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with rails association.
Following link explain you this in details,

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Hi, I've looked over that document and I'm not sure how to add the association. In City, Zip, and Sub-Zip models I believe I use **has_one** but I don't what to use in the **Stat** model. If a Stat only belongs to City I would use **belongs_to** but in this case it could belong to many models.

Comment: if stat and other models like city has many to many association, then you have to use has_and_belongs_to_many association. This can be done with join table. Look for this in same link.